# Who gets the ads revenue on a Custom search engine created by me?

Tags: google-programmable-search-engine

I see a switch that I can turn on this for my CSE. I am just wondering, who gets the revenue of this ads?

If I turn it on, will the revenue 100% goes to my account?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not you enable "Search Engine Monitization" Google will show ads your custom search engine.

- When that checkbox is "off", Google will keep 100% of the revenue.
- When that checkbox is "on", Google will share the revenue with you via your AdSense account.

When Google shares revenue through your AdSense account, they tell you the revenue share percentage.   You can find that information under "Account" -> "Account information".   The revenue share for search is usually 51%.  Google keeps about half of the revenue, and gives you the other half. See [AdSense revenue share - AdSense Help](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/180195?hl=en)